# How does di-isobutylaluminium hydride ( DiBAl-H ) reduces carboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

$\text{DiBAl-H}$ reduces by electrophilic attack and provides hydrogen by $\text{H}^-$ transfer. Unlike $\text{LiAlH}_4$ it does not directly provide $\text{H}^-$ ion. So it should not undergo acid base reaction with carboxylic acid. But my friend argued that it undergoes acid base reaction. I can't find any reaction mechanism for reduction of carboxylic acid with $\text{DiBAl-H}$, can someone propose a mechanism for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduction of esters of carboxylic acids directly to aldehydes is of great synthetic interest. Zakharkin and Khorlina in 1962 (Ref.1) has shown that, diisobutylaluminum hydride (DIBAL-H) could be very useful in reducing esters to aldehyde in high yields at low temperatures (about $\pu{-70 ^oC}$). They also found that solvents affect reduction significantly. For example, the reduction reaction in toluene or hexane proceeds to give corresponding aldehydes in yields l0-15% more than those in ether as the solvent. Previously, in 1959, Miller *et al.* (Ref.2) found that DIBAL-H is a more selective reagent than lithium aluminum hydride in the reduction of nitriles to aldehydes, and it can also be used to reduce benzoic acid to give 72% yields of benzyl alcohol (they also showed esters can be reduced to corresponding alcohols). The conditions and yields of these references are summarized in [this page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87877/does-dibal-h-reduce-carboxylic-acids). In Ref.2, during acid reduction, Miller *et al.* have used 3 equivalents of DIBAL-H and observed that a gas (hydrogen) evaluation upon the addition of the hydride to benzoic acid until one mole of the reducing agent had reacted. Thereafter, the addition of more DIBAL-H gave no gas. Thus, the first reaction is, presumably an acid-base reaction. However, DIBAL-H here should be acting as a Lewis-acid instead of a base, as illustrated in scheme 1:

[image: DIBAL as Lewis Acid]

The ist mono-adduct, then further reacted with second DIBAL-H to give di-adduct, which upon acid hydrolysis would give expected aldehyde (Scheme 2):

[image: Carb Acid Reduction]

---

References:

1. L. I. Zakharkin, I. M. Khorlina, “Reduction of esters of carboxylic acids directly into aldehydes with diisobutylaluminum hydride,” *Tetrahedron Letters* **1962**, *(14)*, 619-620 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)70918-X).
2. A. E. G. Miller, J. W. Biss, and L. H. Schwartzman, “Reductions with Dialkylaluminum Hydrides,” *J. Org. Chem.* **1959**, *24(5)*, 627–630 (DOI: 10.1021/jo01087a013).

Answer (score 0):

**At lower temperatures (around -78oC), carboxylic acids (with 2 equiv. of DIBAL-H) is reduced by DIBAL-H**

[image]

Comment: What does aqueous base have to do with the question? Two equivalents of DIBAL-H may be required. One as a base; one as a reductant. The bis-aluminum complex (lower right corner) must be stable prior to work up at low temperature.

Comment: @Sarahjane this does not answer the initial part of my question. Further this mechanism does not seem to be correct. 1 eq. of DiBAl-H can reduce ester, here's the mechanism (
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dwzk.jpg ). So why does carboxylate Ion require 2 eq. of DiBAl-H inspite being more electron rich?